# Creating a client app for chat in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, client, client-server

I am trying to create simple chat in C#, WinForms.

```
        TcpClient client;
        public MainWindow()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.100", 1234);
          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
          ReadAsync(client,logbox);
        }

    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        string text = textBox.Text;
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        NetworkStream stream  = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data,0,text.Length);
    }
    static async void ReadAsync(TcpClient client, RichTextBox box)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
            box.AppendText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
        }
    }
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.Close();
    }
```

I have problem with sendButton_Click, sending function don't work.
I think, it waiting for stream.Close(); to send data, but I need this stream for receiving data.

Comment: Do this throw any exception?

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong with the code above. So whatever your problem, it's in the code you didn't share. Your question needs to include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. With networking code, this means you need to include [mcve] for both client and server. Also, you need to provide a more specific problem statement than _"don't work"_.

Comment: Debuger shows nothing. My server side:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cSgKZRnZ

Comment: I created something similar some time ago: https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35. It supports multiple clients with bi-directional streams

Answer (score -1):

You should use Sockets, this is a example of a simple chat winforms:

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ChatServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
            counter = 0;
            while ((true))
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1000025];
                string dataFromClient = null;

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

                clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

                broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
            {
                TcpClient broadcastSocket;
                broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
                NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
                Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

                if (flag == true)
                {
                    broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                }

                broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
                broadcastStream.Flush();
            }
        } 
    }


    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        string clNo;
        Hashtable clientsList;

        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            this.clNo = clineNo;
            this.clientsList = cList;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void doChat()
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[100025];
            string dataFromClient = null;
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            string serverResponse = null;
            string rCount = null;
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                    Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }//end while
        }//end doChat
    } //end class handleClinet
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
namespace ChatClientForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox3.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void getMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[100025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        }

        private void msg()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            else
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It fails to, in any way, explain why the OP's code doesn't work. Note also that your claim that the OP should be using sockets is foolish. They are using `TcpClient` which is just a wrapper around sockets, and which is a perfectly fine way to do network operations. Finally, posts that are just code dumps, without any useful explanation, are not useful.